Invalidate Init of the Provisioned Concurrency on demand on Lambda
I have a use case where I have written some logic to read the data from the SSM parameter store in the init section of the lambda. Post which I have published the version and live alias. Now I have added 10 provisioned concurrency.
Post which I have updated the values in the SSM parameter store, Now I wanted the new value of the parameter store to be reflected in the Provisioned concurrency. Is there any way I can do this on demand.
I am aware that the below options will do it but still exploring for more options.

Deleting the provisioned concurrency and adding the provisioned concurrency again.
Publishing the new version for the alias.

